# Best way to run process on certain hours

Tags: c#, service

Hi I have a **Windows Service** in `C#`. Inside my windows service I need to run a process on determined hours hh:mm:ss.

For example I need to run the process at:

- 09:50 hrs
- 11.45 hrs
- 15:15 hrs
- 22:05 hrs

(These hours can change, so Im thinking in storing those in a XML file)

Right now I used to have a timer with interval of 6 hours, so every 6 hours the process was executed. Now the requirement is other. I need to run on a specific schedule.

Also I was requested to add an option that the windows service can run the process on every X hours and Y minutes.

Any clue how can I code that?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for here? Anything other then "*use timers*"?

Comment: I would like to know the best way to check for those specific hours. I was thinking in setting my timer to 1 interval of 1 second and then verify if the hour is the machine hour and then execute it.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan.

Comment: can you not just use a scheduler program to execute your windows service.. and if not then use a .config file that has a string array of the hours that you want to run the program..

Comment: Do you care about changes to system time as provided various authorities, e.g. Daylight Saving Time? Quartz (as suggested by Reza) can help with that. Leap seconds may be another issue. ([Ref](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/faq.html).)

Answer (score 2):

Another good way could be using [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

> **Quartz.NET**
>   Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that
>   can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.
>
> **Job Scheduling in Quartz**
>   Jobs are scheduled to run when a given Trigger occurs.
>   Triggers can be created with nearly any combination of the following
>   directives:
>
> - at a certain time of day (to the millisecond)
> - on certain days of the week
> - on certain days of the month
> - on certain days of the year
> - not on certain days listed within a registered Calendar (such as business holidays)
> - repeated a specific number of times
> - repeated until a specific time/date
> - repeated indefinitely
> - repeated with a delay interval

Comment: Just came in to recommend this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? Just use Windows Task Scheduler to run your process.

If you want to setup the task scheduler from your code, you can use the [Managed Task Scheduler Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)